# MySql - inner join roda no PHPADMIN mas no SCRIPT php não

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner

Tenho um pequeno script PHP para interagir com MAKERIOD.
Quando executo o select no PHPADMIN tenho o retorno :
"A mostrar registos de 0 - 16 (17 total, A consulta demorou 8.0945 segundos.)"

```
SELECT Tbdiario.cn1, Tbdiario.cn2, Tbdiario.cn3, Tbdiario.cn4, Alunos.cnomealu, Tbmateria.cnomemat FROM tbdiario INNER JOIN tbementa ON Tbdiario.ccodementa = Tbementa.ccodementa INNER JOIN tbmateria ON Tbementa.ncodmat = Tbmateria.ncodmat INNER JOIN alunos ON Tbdiario.ncodaluno = Alunos.ncodaluno INNER JOIN tbturma ON Tbementa.ncodtur = Tbturma.ncodtur WHERE Alunos.ccpf = '13922054765' AND Tbturma.cletivo = '2009'
```

Porem quero rodar esse SELECT dentro de um .PHP passando como parametros o CPF e o ano LETIVO. 
Mas quando ponho para executar http://localhost/lernotas.php dá tempo esgotado ; ja alterei esse limite de tempo( o que não acho correto ) mas não retorna nada.

```
//include_once 'conexao.php';
require "Dbig.class.php";
Header('Content-Type: application/json');
//$c_cpf = $_POST['c_cpf']  ;
//$c_anoletivo = $_POST['c_anoletivo'];
$db = new Db();
$dados=array();

$sqlBusca = 'SELECT Tbdiario.cn1, Tbdiario.cn2, Tbdiario.cn3, Tbdiario.cn4,';
$sqlBusca .=' Alunos.cnomealu, Tbmateria.cnomemat FROM tbdiario ';
$sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbementa ON  Tbdiario.ccodementa = Tbementa.ccodementa ';
$sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbmateria ON  Tbementa.ncodmat = Tbmateria.ncodmat ';
$sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN alunos  ON  Tbdiario.ncodaluno = Alunos.ncodaluno ';
$sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbturma ON  Tbementa.ncodtur = Tbturma.ncodtur ';
$sqlBusca .=' WHERE  Alunos.ccpf = "13922054765" ';


$resultado = $db->query($sqlBusca);
if ($resultado)
{
    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
    {
        $dados[] = $array;
    }
    echo json_encode($dados);
}     
else{
    echo "VAZIO !!!";
}
```

?>

```
<?php

/**
*  conexão com o banco de dados usando mysqli
*/
class Db{

    private $con;

    // Faz a conexão com o banco assim que o objeto é criado
    function __construct(){
        $this->con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbcadastro');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($this->con)) {
            echo "Problemas para conectar no banco. Verifique os dados!";
            die();
        }
    }

    // Faz a consulta sql
    public function query($sql){
        return mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Qual a versão do php instalada?

Comment: Xampp 3.22 Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.33 Versão do cliente de base de dados: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11
PHP Version 5.5.33

Comment: Se eu troco aquele SELECT por esse $sqlBusca = 'SELECT Alunos.cnomealu,Alunos.ccpf,Tbdiario.cn1,Tbdiario.cn2,Tbdiario.cn3 FROM alunos INNER JOIN tbdiario ON  Alunos.ncodaluno=Tbdiario.ncodaluno WHERE  Alunos.ccpf =13922054765'; funciona ....mas preciso do campo ANOLETIVO e por isso vários INNER JOIN

Comment: Pode ser algum problema com o CaseSensitive, dependendo do SO que está instalado.

Comment: Win 7 original .

Comment: Altera o teu SQL para ficar certinho como estão criadas as tabelas e colunas no banco de dados. Eu acho que o PHPMyAdmin já trata isso para desconsiderar.

Comment: Diario - fk ncodalu , Diario - fk ccodementa , Tbementa - fk ncodtur e Tbementa - fk ncodmat é assim...

Comment: Desculpa, Marcondes, o que você quer dizer "ltera o teu SQL para ficar certinho como estão criadas as tabelas e colunas no banco de dados." ?

Comment: Pessoal , verifiquei e vi que tinha que trocar a ordem das tabelas : estava DIARIO-EMENTA-MATERIA-ALUNOS-TURMA e mudei para DIARIO- ALUNOS-EMENTA-TURMA-MATERIA , com o objetivo de mostrar nome do aluno , da materia ( disciplina ) e as respectivas notas.

Answer (score 0):

verifiquei e vi que tinha que trocar a ordem das tabelas : estava DIARIO-EMENTA-MATERIA-ALUNOS-TURMA e mudei para DIARIO- ALUNOS-EMENTA-TURMA-MATERIA , com o objetivo de mostrar nome do aluno , da materia ( disciplina ) e as respectivas notas.
Executo no navegador e tenho o retorno ; porem quando insiro o campo Tbmateria.cnomemat ( nome da disciplina ) o retorno é o browser vazio ( sem nada nem a mensagem de "Select Vazio" ) Qualquer campo da tabela Tbmateria eu consigo retornar , menos o que quero . `$sqlBusca  = 'SELECT Tbmateria.ncodmat, Alunos.cnomealu, Tbdiario.cn1, Tbdiario.cn2, Tbdiario.cn3, Tbdiario.cn4 FROM ';
    $sqlBusca .=' tbdiario INNER JOIN alunos ON Alunos.ncodaluno = Tbdiario.ncodaluno ';
    $sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbementa ON Tbdiario.ccodementa = Tbementa.ccodementa ';
    $sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbmateria ON Tbmateria.ncodmat = Tbementa.ncodmat  ';
    $sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbturma ON Tbementa.ncodtur = Tbturma.ncodtur';
    $sqlBusca .=' WHERE Alunos.ccpf= "13922054765" Order by tbmateria.cnomemat ';`

O retorno é Json :
[image: Observem o campo tbmateria.ncodmat , retorna OK]

Mudando apenas o campo tbmateria.ncodmat pot tbmateria.cnomemat ( é o que me interessa ) :

```
$sqlBusca  = 'SELECT Tbmateria.cnomemat, Alunos.cnomealu, Tbdiario.cn1, Tbdiario.cn2, Tbdiario.cn3, Tbdiario.cn4 FROM ';
$sqlBusca .=' tbdiario INNER JOIN alunos ON Alunos.ncodaluno = Tbdiario.ncodaluno ';
$sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbementa ON Tbdiario.ccodementa = Tbementa.ccodementa ';
$sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbmateria ON Tbmateria.ncodmat = Tbementa.ncodmat  ';
$sqlBusca .=' INNER JOIN tbturma ON Tbementa.ncodtur = Tbturma.ncodtur';
$sqlBusca .=' WHERE Alunos.ccpf= "13922054765" Order by tbmateria.cnomemat ';
```

Resultado , vazio ... nem entrou no ELSE que trata o retorno vazio :
[image: Vazio sem mensagem de erro]

Qualquer campo da tabela TBMATERIA ( ncodmat,cabrev e ctipo ) o Select retorna o Json certo, somente o campo cnomemat não.
Se eu acrescentar na cláusula WHERE , Tbmateria.ncodmat = 77 ( um codigo qualquer aleatório ) o Select retorna os registros corretos.